# R solver for non linear constraints

Tags: r, max, minimum

Is there R solver function similar to solve.QP but for non linear constraints? Also, is there another generic solver for cubic or higher degree contraints and minimum/maximum functions?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions copied verbatim from the [Optimisation Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/):

- Rsolnp is currently being developed on  [R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/)  in project [rino](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rino/). This package offers general nonlinear optimization using the augmented lagrange multiplier method.
- In package  [Rdonlp2](http://arumat.net/Rdonlp2/)  function donlp2(), a wrapper for the DONLP2 solver, offers the minimization of smooth nonlinear functions and constraints. DONLP2 can be used freely for any kind of research purposes, otherwise it requires licensing.